# Intellisense to SPWebApplication missing

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint Development and I am trying to get a reference to the `SPWebApplication` Class. However even after adding `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration`. I am still not getting intellisense to the `SPWebApplication` object. I am using SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2013.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. 
I had initially started up with the deploy as a Sandbox Solution checked when creating the solution. After changing it to Deploy as a Farm Solution every thing now works.